# Latex table error, Forbidden control sequence

Tags: tables, errors

Im trying to make a table in LaTEX and my code looks like this:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Comparing all interactions with time at each timestep. The model for All are the full model shown in Table \ref{ANOVA1} and the timesteps are calculated from  $Y_{t}=Sex*Concentration*Line*Temperature$ where  $Y_{t}$ is the distance travelled from the previous timestep. \textbf{Bold text} shows the significant results at 95\% confides interval. }
\label{time:anova}
\begin{tabular}{l|lllll}
Time         & Sex       & DGRP-Line         & Temperatuer & Concentration & DGRP-Line and temperature \\ \hline
All         \textbf{ & 0.049 }    & \textbf{2.2e-16 & 0.0007}      & \textbf{0.038}     & \textbf{ 2.882e-06}              \\
0-0,5 second & 0.8444407 & \textbf{4.244e-10}         & 0.2720534   & 0.1375129     & \textbf{0.0006659}                 \\
0,5-1 second &\textbf{ 0.0004} &          & 0.0031148   & 0.0995024     & \textbf{0.0280461 }                \\
1-1,5 second & \textbf{0.0005} & 0.3664504         & \textbf{1.948e-07}   & 0.0611781     & 0.1679611                 \\
1,5-2 second &\textbf{ 0.0026}  & 0.531987          & 0.079998    & 0.087518      & 0.902758                  \\
2-2,5 second & 0.29189   & 0.05216           & \textbf{0.03220}    & 0.89924       & 0.77766                   \\
2,5-3 second & 0.64682   & 0.08111           & 0.63522     & 0.32285       & 0.45075                  
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

When I try to build I get the error:

> Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \check@nocorr@.

It says that I'm missing an `}` but I cannot seem to figure out where that `}` is missing, can someone help me with that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 4):

The error is very straight forward you have two additional & signs inside you `\textbf{}` functions in the second row.

The following should work:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Comparing all interactions with time at each timestep. The model for All are the full model shown in Table  and the timesteps are calculated from  $Y_{t}=Sex*Concentration*Line*Temperature$ where  $Y_{t}$ is the distance travelled from the previous timestep. \textbf{Bold text} shows the significant results at 95\% confides interval. }
\label{time:anova}
\begin{tabular}{l|lllll}
Time & Sex & DGRP-Line & Temperatuer & Concentration & DGRP-Line and temperature \\ 
\hline
All  &\textbf{0.049 } & \textbf{2.2e-16} & \textbf{0.0007} & \textbf{0.038} & \textbf{2.882e-06} \\
0-0,5 second & 0.8444407 & \textbf{4.244e-10}  & 0.2720534   & 0.1375129     & \textbf{0.0006659} \\
0,5-1 second &\textbf{0.0004} & & 0.0031148 & 0.0995024 & \textbf{0.0280461 } \\
1-1,5 second & \textbf{0.0005} & 0.3664504 & \textbf{1.948e-07}  & 0.0611781 & 0.1679611 \\
1,5-2 second &\textbf{0.0026}  & 0.531987 & 0.079998 & 0.087518 & 0.902758 \\
2-2,5 second & 0.29189   & 0.05216 & \textbf{0.03220}    & 0.89924       & 0.77766 \\
2,5-3 second & 0.64682   & 0.08111 & 0.63522 & 0.32285 & 0.45075                  
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

If I could give you advice round the numbers so the table looks a bit better. I will also make spotting mistake easier.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment or edit your answer.